# How react js and other Javascript Technologies works on WordPress plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I hope you are doing well.

I want to start developing a WordPress plugin and this time I would like to do it with react at the front end. However, I have a question:
If I ever create a **WordPress plugin with react will it be able to work independently of the javascript technologies used on the themes**.

**For example if the theme is made with jQuery and the React JS plugin, is that a problem?**

Waiting for an answer, be well, cordially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both libraries are already bundled with wordpress.